# Define a different function for each instance of a class

Tags: c++, class

Say I have this class:

```cpp
class Object {
  public:
    int x;
    int y;

    void update(SDL_Event);
    void start();
};
```

I want to be able to make `start` and `update` change behavior from instance to instance.

I have tried using function pointers, like so:

```cpp
class Object {
  public:
    int x;
    int y;

    void (*update)(SDL_Event);
    void (*start)(void);
};

void teststart() {
  x++;
  return;
}
```

And in my `main()`, I do:

```cpp
testlevel.objs[1].start = teststart;
```

But then, I cannot reference variables from inside the class.

I am sure there is something obvious I am overlooking, but searching online yields no results for when the pointer is in the class.

Maybe function pointers are not the right answer?

Comment: You could potentially use a member function pointer, but what you probably want is either inheritance or composition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need to pass your functions a pointer/reference to the `Object` instance, eg:

```
class Object {
  public:
    int x;
    int y;

    void (*doupdate)(Object*, SDL_Event);
    void (*dostart)(Object*);

    void update(SDL_Event event) { if (doupdate) doupdate(this, event); } 
    void start() { if (dostart) dostart(this); }
};
```

```
void teststart(Object* obj) {
  obj->x++;
}

void testupdate(Object* obj, SDL_Event event) {
  // update obj as needed...
}

Object &obj = testlevel.objs[1];
obj.dostart = teststart;
obj.doupdate = testupdate;
```

Otherwise, use `std::function` with capturing lambdas instead:

```
#include <functional>

class Object {
  public:
    int x;
    int y;

    std::function<void(SDL_Event)> update;
    std::function<void()> start;
};
```

```
Object *obj = &(testlevel.objs[1]);

obj->start = [obj](){
  obj->x++;
};

obj->update = [obj](SDL_Event event){
  // update obj as needed...
};
```

Comment: I had this idea and hoped that there was a more elegant solution, but it seems not. thanks for the example code.

Comment: @Finxx see the update to my answer